# java.lang.NumberFormatException: null - in a do loop

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I keep getting this error in my code and I know it has something to do with the integer not being a number but I am unsure how to fix this. I'm sure this is very basic but so am I so I would appreciate any help possible. This has to be done in a do loop by the way. I know it would be better in a while.

Here are the bits of code which contain the information needed. Thank you.

```
    String firstName, surname, id;
    int luckynumber, lockernumber, grade, age;
    char grade2;

    try {
        BufferedReader filein = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(
                "studentdetails.txt")));
        do {
            id = filein.readLine();
            firstName = filein.readLine();
            surname = filein.readLine();
            age = Integer.parseInt(filein.readLine());
            grade = Integer.parseInt(filein.readLine());
            lockernumber = Integer.parseInt(filein.readLine());
            age = 2010 - age;

        } while (id != null);

        filein.close();


    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
        System.out.println(fnfe);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        System.out.print(nfe);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.print(e);
    }
```

Edit -
This is the file that is read in but with about 10 other people. Each word/number is on its own line in the file.

```
261
Patricia
Halangahu
1974
92
56
```

Comment: we don't know the contents of the file you are reading. check that

Comment: Can you add a sample of the contents in `studentdetails.txt`?

Comment: `studentdetails.txt` and `stackTrack` add first then Only we will be able to help you out

Comment: Side note: `age = 2010 - age;` seems quite odd. With your code Patricia would be 36 now instead of 42 - well, she'd probably like that ;)

Comment: Are you sure that there are no empty lines between the different people? If there is you have to add something to handle that.

Comment: Yeah there are no empty lines and for the program I am supposed to make it for 2010, idk why.

Comment: the number of times you change the `.txt` file content. I have already give you solution according to the first one and again and again changing your requirement is so absurd thing ever i found  @michael

Comment: Im sorry havn't really used Java/this website very much still trying to understand how to fix these things. As to your solution I am only allowed to use code that i have learnt in my class so as good as it may be it is not useful to me, thankyou for still taking the time thouhgh :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the file doesn't contain empty lines which could also trigger a NumberFormatException consider your case:

```
do {
  id = filein.readLine();
  //do more stuff
} while( id != null );
```

You're checking if you reached the end of the file by checking the id for being null. But if `id` is null you're still completing the iteration and the parses will fail (you already reached the end of the file so what should `age = Integer.parseInt(filein.readLine());` do then?).

So how do you solve that? One way would be to add a check right after reading the id:

```
do {
  id = filein.readLine();
  if( id == null) {
    //end of stream, stop iteration
    break;
  }

  //do more stuff

} while( true ); //you're breaking the loop from the inside already
```

Comment: It might also return "seven" instead of "7"

Comment: @Stultuske yes that would be possible but I'm just answering the question at hand and I'm deliberately not covering every possible error (e.g. there might also be a line for `id` but no more lines after that -> "corrupt" file as well).

Comment: Thanks man that fixed the problem and im still getting the correct output, I really appreciate you taking the time to help me thanks :)